# Complex variable equations

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following equation

$\sinh(iz)=-1$

So what I did was to make $\sinh(iz) = i \sin(z)$
And so we have:
$\sin(z)=i$

Then I took $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$

And I solved my equation and got to 
$(e^{iz}+1)^2 = 2$
Then I continued and got to 
$e^{iz} = -1 + \sqrt{2}$ or $e^{iz} = -1 - \sqrt{2}$

Then I made

$z = x + iy$

$-1 + \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{3} e^{i2k\pi}$

$-1 - \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{3} e^{\pi +i2k\pi}$

and in each equality I equaled the real part of each complex and the imaginary part of each complex

My solutions are:
$z = 2k\pi - i \log(\sqrt{3})$ and $z = \pi + 2k\pi - i \log(\sqrt{3})$

However my professor solution is

$z = 2k\pi - i \log(\sqrt{2} - 1)$ and $z = \pi + 2k\pi - i \log(\sqrt{2} + 1)$

Are this solution equivalent or what have I done wrong in my calculations?
Can someone give a little hand? Thanks!

Comment: You could've more easily started with $\sinh(x)=-1$, solve for $x$, then have $x=iz$.  This way, the complex numbers only appear at the end, unless we account for branches, which would appear at the $\log$ step.

Answer (score 1):

$$i\sin z=i\,\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=-1\iff\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{2e^{iz}}=-e^{iz}\iff$$

$$3e^{2iz}=1\implies3e^{-2y+2ix=1}\implies\begin{cases}I\;\;\;\;3e^{-2y}\cos 2x=1\\{}\\II\;\;\;e^{-2y}\sin 2x=0\end{cases}\stackrel{II}\implies 2 x=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;\implies$$

$$x=\frac{k\pi}2\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\stackrel{I}\implies3e^{-2y}=1\,,\,\,k\in2\Bbb Z\implies2y=\log3\implies y=\frac12\log3=\log\sqrt3$$

and thus I agree with you and your teacher is wrong...or you and I both are, of course.

Comment: Typo at the end?

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks. I just hit the "post your answer" button without even paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I just figured it out!

I was incorrectly writing:

$-1 + \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{3} e^{i2k\pi}$

$-1 - \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{3} e^{\pi +i2k\pi}$

The correct way should be:

$-1 + \sqrt{2} = (-1 + \sqrt{2}) e^{i2k\pi}$

$-1 - \sqrt{2} = (1 + \sqrt{2}) e^{\pi +i2k\pi}$

From this point,everything is solved correctly and we get to my professor answer.